# How to check whether a String contains '\r' \t' '\n'...other than spaces

Tags: java, regex

How to check whether a String contains all '\r' \t' '\n'...other than spaces?

For example, `String a = "a\nb"`, `String b = "a b"`. I want return true for string a, false for string b.

I know there is `Character.isWhiteSpace(char c)`, and `Pattern.compile("\\s").matcher(string).find()`. But they all take space(' ') into account. What I want is find out all escape characters which is considered as whitespace by `Character.isWhiteSpace(char c)` method except for ' '.

And I don't want to check char by char, it will be the best if there is a proper regex and I can use like `Pattern.compile`.

Comment: 1st, remove spaces, then check?

Comment: Why not check for `/\n|\r|\t/`?

Comment: @antoni because I want to find out all whitespace defined by Character.isWhitespace(char) other than space itself. I think except for \n|\r|\t, there must be more escape characters that Character.isWhitespace(char) defines as whitespace

Comment: @GregaMohorko: That's a way also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `[^\S ]` which matches everything but `\S` (non-whitespace) or  (space).

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\S ]");

String a = "a\nb";
String b = "a b";

System.out.println(pattern.matcher(a).find()); // true
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(b).find()); // false
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
@Test
    public void testLines() {
        assertTrue(Pattern.compile("[\n\r\t]").matcher("a\nb").find());
        assertFalse(Pattern.compile("[\n\r\t]").matcher("a b").find());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you say "all '\r' \t' '\n'...other than spaces", what you mean is "any whitespace character other than U+0020" (where U+0020 is a simple space).  Is this correct?

If so, then the following regex (general form) should work:

```
(?! )\s
```

This will match any whitespace character that is not a simple space.  This regex makes use of [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

---

EDIT:

As @Bubletan states in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41372116/5029307), the following regex will also work:

```
[^\S ]
```

Both of these regex are equivalent.  This is because `(?! )\s ≣ "(is NOT the character U+0020) AND (is whitespace)"` and `[^\S ] ≣ "is NOT (non-whitespace OR the character U+0020)` have the same truth table:

```
Let P(x) be the predicate "x is the character U+0020"
Let Q(x) be the predicate "x is whitespace"

P | Q | (¬P)∧Q | ¬(¬Q∨P)
–– ––– –––––––– ––––––––
T   T      F       F
T   F      T       T
F   T      F       F
F   F      F       F
```

Although for the sake of efficiency, you are probably better off using @Bubletan's solution (`[^\S ]`).  Lookaround is generally slower than the alternative.

This is how you could implement it:

```
// Create the pattern.  (do only once)
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\S ]");

// Test an input string.  (do for each input)
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
boolean result = matcher.find();
```

`result` will then indicate whether `string` contains any whitespace other than a simple space.

Comment: That's a very detailed answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Java, use `[^\\h]+` . \h means all kinds of horizontal spaces. But in other languages, it is not available as far as I know.