# Determine if a String contains *exactly* 3 words and *exactly* 2 whitespaces in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I basically want to check if a string is formatted exactly as: `"WORD1 WORD2 WORD3"`, where WORD1, WORD2, and WORD3 are any arbitray words. In short, I'm trying to check if a string contains *exactly* two whitespaces and *exactly* three words; no numbers and no symbols other than regular letters.

I've looked extensively at other posts regarding regex in Java but none of those posts seem to say how to match exactly *n* whitespaces. Similar posts are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067809/how-can-i-find-whitespace-in-a-string), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372011/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-r-t-n-other-than-spaces), and but they only seem to explain how to find strings that *only* contain whitespaces or if they contain *any* whitespaces.

I looked at the [Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) Java documentation on how to match spaces and it says that this: **[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]** matches "a whitespace character", which I believe includes the space, tab, newline, , form-feed, and carriage return characters.

But when I implement the code in Java, I don't get what I expect:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WhiteSpace{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b = Pattern.matches("[ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]", "word word word"); 
        System.out.println(b); // This prints false instead of true even though there are 2 spaces in the string.
    }
}
```

Even trying just `"[ ]"` or `"\\s"` doesn't seem to work. I don't have any luck with quantifiers either, such as **x{2}?** (to match *x* exactly twice). And the baffling thing is that when I try out the same thing on a regex tester website (such as [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)), I **do** indeed get the 2 matches that I want.

Some feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: `Pattern.matches()` tries to match the _entire input string_;  you'd need to do `Pattern.compile("[ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]").matcher("word word word").find()` to find a match within the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `String#matches` here, with the following regex pattern:

```
\S+\s\S+\s\S+
```

Sample script:

```
String input = "WORD1 WORD2\tWORD3";
if (input.matches("\\S+\\s\\S+\\s\\S+")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

The above pattern should work for 3 words with exactly two whitespace characters, because there is no other way to arrange the 3 words to achieve this requirement.

**Edit:**

If you want to only admit "regular" letters in the three words, then use:

```
(?i)[A-Z]+\s[A-Z]+\s[A-Z]+
```

Comment: ...of course it also matches `"%\n%\n%"`, which at first glance looks looks like one bad word.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The original requirements were worded "whitespace" characters.  Of course, if we want to allow for only space, we can use `\S+ \S+ \S+`.

Comment: Incorrect answer. Question said *"no numbers and no symbols other than regular letters"*, so using `\S` is incorrect, since it matches both numbers and symbols. The correct pattern would be `\p{L}`, or `\p{Alpha}`, or `[a-zA-Z]`. If using `\p{L}`, then `\s` should likely be replace with `\p{Zs}`, and if using `\p{Alpha}`, then `\s` should likely be replace with `\p{Space}`.

Comment: Tim, don't feel bad about misreading the question. I rarely get them right myself. After reading a bit my mind invariably starts twisting the words to make the question more interesting.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I know where the misread happened.  I read the title of the question, and the first two sentences, and duped myself into thinking that I had all requirements `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Split the string and test each part.

```
var count = 0;
for (var s : input.split(" ")) {
  if (s.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
    count++;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
return count == 3;
```

It does work:

https://repl.it/repls/TruthfulLuxuriousOmnipage#Main.java

Comment: Why use multiple regex's and a loop, when it can be done in a single regex?